# Add variable/Label to a list as a tuple

Tags: python, list, tkinter, label

I wish to record labels, produced by a function, in a list. This is completely for the purpose of using these later on to delete them, using the label.place_forget(). Because many labels are produced when I call the function, and I call the funtion many times. I have created my list outside of the function, and then inside my function I have called the list.extend() to add the variables/lables to the list. However when I print the list, after the function has been called, It appears the memory location of the variable is stored. Here is my code...

```
import sys, tkinter, csv
from tkinter import *

playerRows = []

def playerTab(team, name, pos, pts, reb, ast, stl, blk, to, y):
        global playerRows
        #Print the team
        playerTeam = Label(statWindow, bg = "white", text = team)
        playerTeam.config(height = 1, width = 13)
        playerTeam.place(x=20,y=y)
        #Print the name
        playerName = Label(statWindow, bg = "white", text = name)
        playerName.config(height = 1, width = 25)
        playerName.place(x=119,y=y)
        #Print the players position
        playerPosition = Label(statWindow, bg = "white", text = pos)
        playerPosition.config(height = 1, width = 4)
        playerPosition.place(x=302,y=y)
        #Print the players average points
        playerPoints = Label(statWindow, bg = "white", text = pts)
        playerPoints.config(height = 1, width = 4)
        playerPoints.place(x=338,y=y)
        #Print the players average rebounds
        playerRebounds = Label(statWindow, bg = "white", text = reb)
        playerRebounds.config(height = 1, width = 4)
        playerRebounds.place(x=374,y=y)
        #Print the players average assists
        playerAssists = Label(statWindow, bg = "white", text = ast)
        playerAssists.config(height = 1, width = 4)
        playerAssists.place(x=410,y=y)
        #Print the players average steals
        playerSteals = Label(statWindow, bg = "white", text = stl)
        playerSteals.config(height = 1, width = 4)
        playerSteals.place(x=446,y=y)
        #Print the players average blocks
        playerBlocks = Label(statWindow, bg = "white", text = blk)
        playerBlocks.config(height = 1, width = 4)
        playerBlocks.place(x=482,y=y)
        #Print the players average turnovers
        playerTurnovers = Label(statWindow, bg = "white", text = to)
        playerTurnovers.config(height = 1, width = 4)
        playerTurnovers.place(x=518,y=y)


        playerRows.extend((playerTeam, playerName, playerPosition, playerPoints, playerRebounds, playerAssists, playerSteals, playerBlocks, playerTurnovers))
        return playerTeam, playerName, playerPosition, playerPoints, playerRebounds, playerAssists, playerSteals, playerBlocks, playerTurnovers





playerTab(row['Team'], (row['First Name'] + ' ' + row['Last Name']), row['Position'], row['Average PTS'], row['Average REB'], row['Average AST'], row['Average STL'], row['Average BLK'], row['Average TO'], 120)
```

When I call print to print the list, I can see that the values being added to the list are...

```
[(<tkinter.Label object at 0x00000000035E8F28>, <tkinter.Label object at 0x00000000035E8B70>, <tkinter.Label object at 0x00000000035E8BE0>)]
```

Therefore, how can I save the labels in the list so that I can reference them later on in order to remove them.

Comment: you're returning from your function _before_ appending! (and there's a syntax error, you don't append a list to another one, you _extend_ it)

Comment: Your playerRows.append line is after the function's return statement so it is never executed.

Answer (score 0):

Since your list contains widget instances, and because you don't do an explicit conversion to strings, python must convert the objects to strings implicitly. When it does so, it will print a label like `<tkinter.Label object at 0x00000000035E8F28>`. Python has no way of knowing that what you really want is the value of the "text" configuration option.

If you want to print the label text, you have to call the `cget` method for each element in each row:

```
for row in playerRows:
    data = [label.cget("text") for label in row]
    print(data)
```

Comment: However the text of the label does not enable me to delete that label, it is the name of the variable to which the label has been defined, which I can use to delete the label.

Comment: @H.Lev: correct. You're storing the actual label itself in the list, so this shouldn't be a problem. This answer specifically addresses the problem you wrote about -- that _printing_ the result gives you something you don't expect. You can still access the individual label widgets from the list.

Comment: Okay, so in that case how would I be able to 'remove' one of the label widgets in the list (not in the sense of removing it from the list, but removing it from the window that it is being shown on).

Comment: @H.Lev: you would call `destroy()` or `place_forget` on each widget, depending on if you want to destroy it or just remove it from view.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of how to do this using the <tkinter.Label object at 0x00000000035E8F28> instance in the list? As I am not familiar with this and im finding it hard to grasp. Thankyou

Comment: No worries, iv'e cracked it. Thanks!